# Too many nodes running in result of Kubernetes autoscaler activity

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

In one of my node pools (in AKS k8s cluster) K8s scheduler placed only 4 Redis pods (controlled by stateful set) while this node could easily serve more pods like this. This is checked via `htop` which shows that the resources usage is really small. Then autoscaler kicks in and scales up the cluster to another node from this node pool. Another 4 Redis pods are placed there. This way I've ended up using 8 nodes, everyone has 4 Redis pods (+ some system pods). It seems that autoscaler kick too early and more pods could be packed into one node.

The part of the result of `kubectl describe node [the name of the node]` is as fallows:

```
Non-terminated Pods:          (11 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                         CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                         ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  akastor                     redis-master-0                               200m (10%)    300m (15%)  400Mi (7%)       600Mi (11%)    3h12m
  icegroup                    redis-master-0                               200m (10%)    300m (15%)  400Mi (7%)       600Mi (11%)    51m
  kube-system                 azure-ip-masq-agent-wd7qk                    100m (5%)     500m (26%)  50Mi (0%)        250Mi (4%)     16h
  kube-system                 cloud-node-manager-nb4m4                     50m (2%)      2 (105%)    50Mi (0%)        512Mi (9%)     16h
  kube-system                 csi-azuredisk-node-5wwn5                     30m (1%)      0 (0%)      60Mi (1%)        400Mi (7%)     16h
  kube-system                 csi-azurefile-node-qm95l                     30m (1%)      0 (0%)      60Mi (1%)        500Mi (9%)     16h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-vg2hl                             100m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         16h
  kube-system                 omsagent-7pfzt                               150m (7%)     1 (52%)     550Mi (10%)      1774Mi (33%)   15h
  ngiskredvarsel              redis-master-0                               200m (10%)    300m (15%)  400Mi (7%)       600Mi (11%)    47m
  prometheus                  prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-x8p2w    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         16h
  tunmedia                    redis-master-0                               200m (10%)    300m (15%)  400Mi (7%)       600Mi (11%)    46m
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests      Limits
  --------           --------      ------
  cpu                1260m (66%)   4700m (247%)
  memory             2370Mi (44%)  5836Mi (108%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)        0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)        0 (0%)
```

Why autoscaler kicks in so fast? How can I pack more pods into one node, ie. optimize costs?

Comment: It looks like 66% of the node's CPU is used in pods' resource requests (actual CPU usage doesn't matter).  If each pod needs 0.2 core or 10% of your node, only 3 more pods would fit on the node.

Comment: So if I would decrease resources requests of CPU to eg. 50m then it should fit more pods on the node? Also, How can I check that what is the threshold of CPU/memory after which the autoscaler kicks in?